# JavaScript keydown event is not triggering with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, keydown, eventtrigger, onkeydown

I want to automatically trigger a `keydown` event after specific amount of time has passed. I set up a timout event for this with the code below:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        document.querySelector("body").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
            keyCode: 83,
            altKey: true
        }));
    },
    12000
);
```

However, it doesn't seem to trigger anything. Could anyone please help me in figuring out how can i send a keydown event in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it triggers alright:

```js
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  console.log('triggered', e)
})

setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.querySelector("body").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        keyCode: 83,
        altKey: true
      }));
    },
    2000
);
```